# TensoriaCalc does not display the correct output

Tags: symbolic, physics, tensors, differential-geometry

I am trying to use TensoriaCalc to calculate the components of the Ricci and the Riemann tensor of the following metric: $R^{2} \left(d\theta^{2} + \sin^{2}\left(\theta \right)d\phi^{2} \right)$;

According to the web guide, I should use this code:

```
Clear[i, j, R, \[Theta], g];
g["2Sphere"] = Metric[
  SubMinus[i], SubMinus[j],
  R^2 ({{1, 0},{0, Sin[\[Theta]]^2}}),
  CoordinateSystem -> {\[Theta], \[Phi]},
  TensorName -> "h",
  StartIndex -> 1,
   ChristoffelOperator -> FullSimplify,
   RiemannOperator -> FullSimplify,
   RicciOperator -> FullSimplify,
  RicciScalarOperator -> FullSimplify
   ]
```

and the output should be:

[image]

However, using the same code in my notebook, in Mathematica version 12.3, I have the following output:

[image]

which is not the result I was expecting.

Does anyone have any idea why this happens?

Comment: I am not familiar with the package, but why don't you calculate these things in Mathematica without a package? I am asking just out of curiosity

Comment: Using the package would take less effort to compute it. However, if I can't solve this problem I may have to calculate it without a package.

Comment: I have explained in [**`in this answer`**](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/265321/how-to-solve-the-einstein-field-equation-symbolically) how you can do this kind of computations without any packages. It is done for an $\text{AdS}_5$ spacetime, but you should be able to easily adjust to the case of $\text{S}^2$. I have added as many explanatory comments, as possible. If you want you can have a look. If you are having difficulties adjusting to your metric, let me know and I can help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm one of the developers of this package. I'm glad to answer your question.
When we develop the package, we set the `Format` of `Metric`, so that the output is shown like your `Out[3]` result. When you hover your mouse on h_ij, you can directly see the `TensorComponent` of the `Metric`. Using the function `TensorComponent` will also help extract it. Also, if you want to get what you expected instead of the formatted result, operate `FullForm` on your `Metric`.
If you want to extract the other geometrical objects, try to use Functions: `Christoffel`, `Riemann`, `Ricci`, `Einstein`, and so on.